# Why are auto layout constraints not properly installed when my app loads in split screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

Auto Layout constraints work for my app on iPad if it loads full screen.

When I go into split screen, everything changes as expected.

When the split screen size changes, the method `- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator` is called.

However, **if I load the app in split screen**, the constraints are incorrect from the start.

Also, when resizing to anything other than full screen, the `- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator` is not called.

Here's a video demonstrating the problem. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ksHt8pIz0b0

I'm using Masonry to install the constraints as follows:

```
    [labelLeft remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.equalTo(self.view.left);
        make.centerY.equalTo(self.view.centerY);
        make.width.equalTo(150);
        make.height.equalTo(30);
    }];

    [labelRight remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.right.equalTo(self.view.right);
        make.centerY.equalTo(self.view.centerY);
        make.width.equalTo(150);
        make.height.equalTo(30);
    }];


    [labelTop remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.centerX.equalTo(self.view.centerX);
        make.top.equalTo(self.view.top);
        make.width.equalTo(150);
        make.height.equalTo(30);
    }];


    [labelBottom remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.centerX.equalTo(self.view.centerX);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.view.bottom);
        make.width.equalTo(150);
        make.height.equalTo(30);
    }];
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

**UPDATE:**
I built a fresh app and installed the same constraints. When I ran the same test scenario, it loaded ok in split screen mode.
However, in the test scenario, the `viewWillTransitionToSize:` was properly called when changing screen size after loading in split screen.

Any ideas about anything that might prevent that from being called in my app when loaded in split screen? The app is huge, so I'm looking for general directions to go searching.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [mcve], in particular showing how you create the constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating an empty app with just the constraints I mentioned, and discovering it worked as expected, I realised there was definitely something in my code that was breaking the intended behaviour.

It turns out it was this line in AppDelegate

`self.window.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];`

Which must have been from early days before I was using AutoLayout.

I doubt anyone is going to have the same problems I did, but just in case, be sure to look out for things like that!